# PayPal - How do I add a passthrough HTML variable to a PayPal button?

Tags: paypal

I want to create a simple form where customers can upload a pdf and then press a pay now PayPal button.  Upon opening the page (or upload), a random reference number will be assigned to the button.  Once the PayPal "Pay now" button is pushed, the reference number should be passed through to me alongside the payment info such as mailing address, etc.

How do I create a customized button that takes a random number as a reference into the payment info?  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The `custom` parameter does this with PayPal.
I.e. `<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="aaaaaaaaaaa111111222222bbbbbb">`.

See also [this link](http://www.michaelsherron.com/paypal-IPN-custom-variables) for information on how this applies to PayPal IPN.

Comment: Thanks.  Just one more question.  How do I make that value a random number?  With some sort of java script?  I am not very good at coding.  How would I do that?  Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that's what you want to do? How will you reconcile this data once it comes back to you? If you merely populate it and send it off to PayPal, all you'll have done is send a random piece of gibberish to PayPal. You'll need to store that 'custom' value serverside where it makes sense to you so that you can actually use it. Have you done that?